# cmake ClanLib i can't compile project

Tags: c++11, cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(ClanLib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

SET(ClanLib_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${ClanLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})
FIND_PACKAGE(ClanLib REQUIRED)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(ClanLib ${SOURCE_FILES} main.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ClanLib ${ClanLib_LIBRARY})
```

and cmake give error:

```
Error:By not providing "FindClanLib.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "ClanLib", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ClanLib" with any of the following names:
  ClanLibConfig.cmake   clanlib-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "ClanLib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "ClanLib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "ClanLib" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Comment: When you define project with ClangLib name and trying to find same name later in project using find_package - perhaps you doing something wrong.

Comment: @Sergey i rename project and it doesn't help

Comment: do you have FindClanLib.cmake installed anywhere on your computer?

Comment: @Sergey i install library how write in this page [GNU C++ on Linux](http://clanlib.org/build-environment-linux-gcc.html)

Comment: Then try use http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html

Comment: @Sergey i add  ' set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})  ' and cmake give new error Error:Cannot specify link libraries for target "ClanLib" which is not built by this project.

Comment: i could compile and get message 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): перемещение 0 имеет недопустимый индекс символа 11
and more typical errors

Comment: well, perhaps you should use same <XPREFIX>_CFLAGS and <XPREFIX>_LDFLAGS from PkgConfig.

Comment: @Sergey can you write, how must be cmakelist.txt or give example?

Comment: Here the example (not mine), but using ClanLib https://github.com/alopatindev/game-sdk/blob/746f47be3983d0889f96d82150b0d61af87b57fb/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no FindClanLib.cmake provided by [ClanLib project](http://clanlib.org/) or CMake, so find_package will not work in your case.

For Linux you can use pkg-config facility from [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html).

Here the [example](https://github.com/alopatindev/game-sdk/blob/746f47be3983d0889f96d82150b0d61af87b57fb/CMakeLists.txt) for ClanLib usage on Linux.